# Why does my A6 GPRS connects to my website but not to other pages of it?

Tags: networking, arduino, gsm, gprs

So, I have an A6 GSM/GPRS module (the pro version https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1oFCRxXmWBuNjSspdq6zugXXaj/GPRS-Pro-Serial-A6-GPRS-GSM-Module-Core-DIY-Developemnt-Board-Replace-SIM900.jpg). Well the story goes like this, I have managed to establish an GPRS connection the website that I have made but the problem comes when I want to connect to other pages from the website. For example if I would want to connect to google.com it would work but if I want to connect to google.com/something
 it returns an error that it was unsuccessful in connecting to the given page. Any ideas are welcome I will try all of them. Thank you !

P.S. Commands that I am using :

`AT+CGATT?`

`AT+CGATT=1`

`AT+CIPSTATUS`

`AT+CGDCONT=1, "IP", "live.vodafone.com"`

`AT+CGDCONT?`

`AT+CGACT=1,1`

`AT+CIFSR`

`AT+CIPSTART="TCP","google.com/something",80`

`AT+CIPSEND`

`1A`

`AT+CIPCLOSE`

Comment: Also asked at: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=625010

Comment: with TCP you connect to a host, not to a page. pages are requested with HTTP

Comment: @Juraj ah I am sorry then I was misled by some tuts on the internet, but of http I dont know if the A6 is capable. If you know could you provide me some info ?

Comment: see the manual if you have HTTP related AT commands. if not, then you must send a HTTP GET request over the TCP connection to get the page content.

Comment: @Juraj well I don't have http it seems so I must use GET I guess, thank you for taking your time to answer